# Trouble with ignore_index and concat()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python.  I have 2 dataframes each with a single column.  I want to join them together and keep the values based on their respective positions in each of the tables.

My code looks something like this:

```
huh = pd.DataFrame(columns=['result'], data=['a','b','c','d'])
huh2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['result2'], data=['aa','bb','cc','dd'])
huh2 = huh2.sort_values('result2', ascending=False)
tmp = pd.concat([huh,huh2], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
tmp
```

From the documentation it looks like the `ignore_index` flag and `axis=1` should be sufficient to achieve this but the results obviously disagree.

Current Output:

```
    0   1
0   a   aa
1   b   bb
2   c   cc
3   d   dd
```

Desired Output:

```
    result  result2
0   a       dd
1   b       cc
2   c       bb
3   d       aa
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you concatenate the DataFrames horizontally, then the column names are ignored. If you concatenate vertically, the indexes are ignored. You can only ignore one or the other, not both.

In your case, I would recommend setting the index of "huh2" to be the same as that of "huh".

```
pd.concat([huh, huh2.set_index(huh.index)], axis=1)

  result result2
0      a      dd
1      b      cc
2      c      bb
3      d      aa
```

If you aren't dealing with custom indices, `reset_index` will suffice.

```
pd.concat([huh, huh2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

  result result2
0      a      dd
1      b      cc
2      c      bb
3      d      aa
```